# Java ListSelectionListener interface with keyboard

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have implemented ListSelectionListener as you can see below, so that after a specific line in the first table is being chosen, the second table gets updated accordingly.

```
class SelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    public SelectionListener(){}

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getSource() == myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getSelectionModel() 
            && myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getRowSelectionAllowed()
            && e.getValueIsAdjusting()) 
        {
          int selected = myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getSelectedRow();
            clearjTable(jTable4);
            showSubscribers(selected);
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to invoke the listener not only when the mouse is choosing, but also when the choice is being made from the keyboard?

Comment: From memory, selection may not change until the user presses space or enter - not tested, just working off my morning memory - ths would mean you won't receive selection changed events until then

Comment: the listener is invoked whenever the selection is changed, independent of the the low-level trigger for the change (mouse, keyboard, programmatic, joystick ..) If that's not working in your code, something is wrong in the part you are not showing. BTW: don't forget to check the getValueIsAdjusting property before actually doing stuff

Comment: @kleopatra that check is done (last condition in the if statement), but the check is different then in all other listeners and might explain the problem. I included this remark in my answer

Comment: @Robin shame on me for being too lazy to scroll ;-) What do you mean by _different then all other_?

Comment: @kleopatra typically you do nothing until `getValueIsAdjusting` returns `false`. In this if check, the code is only triggered when the value is adjusting

Comment: @Robin darn .. missed that, so wasn't only scrolling :-) Typo or feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the unusual experience - no notification on selection via keyboard - is a subtle different setting of valueIsAdjusting for keyboard vs. mouse-triggered selection events:

- keyboard triggered selection (even with modifiers) only fires once (with adjusting == false)
- mouse triggered selection always fires twice (first with true, second with false)

That fact combined with the unusual logic (which @Robin spotted, +1 to him :-)

```
if (e.getSource() == myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getSelectionModel() 
        && myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getRowSelectionAllowed()
        // typo/misunderstanding or feature? doing stuff only when adjusting 
        && e.getValueIsAdjusting())
```

(reacting only if the selection *is* adjusting) leads to not seeing keyboard triggered changes.

Comment: +1 for the better explanation to the why. I only assumed that was causing the problem, now I also know why

Comment: Thanks, I changed to && e.getValueIsAdjusting()==false and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to invoke the listener not only when the mouse is choosing, but also when the choice is being made from the keyboard?

The listener will be triggered, independent of the source of the selection change. So yes, this is perfectly possible and even the default behavior. So nothing special must be done to get this working.

Looking at the code of your listener, I would suggest to rewrite it to

```
class SelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {
  public SelectionListener(){}
  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
    if ( e.getValueIsAdjusting() ){
       return;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getSelectionModel() && 
        myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getRowSelectionAllowed() ) {
      int selected = myTrumpsAndMessages.jTable1.getSelectedRow();
      clearjTable(jTable4);
      showSubscribers(selected);
    }
  }
}
```

Note the quick break from the method when `getValueIsAdjusting()` returns `true` as this is the behavior you want in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried a `ListSelectionListener` and the `valueChanged()` event is actually being triggered on keyboard selection change as well. See my example below:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(list.getSelectedValue());
  }
});
```

Comment: Of course, that's because you have'nt checked that e.getValueIsAdjusting())==true. when you omit this, every event is happening twice.

Comment: @Onca you probably want to check for `e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false` rather then `true`. See my answer