# Unexpected event order when clicking on row in Swing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, mouselistener

The default behaviour when clicking on a row in a JTable appears to be...

```
1 event=javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent[ source=javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel 673443626 ~{0} firstIndex= 0 lastIndex= 0 isAdjusting= true ]
2 mousePressed
3 event=javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent[ source=javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel 673443626 ={0} firstIndex= 0 lastIndex= 0 isAdjusting= false ]
4 mouseReleased
5 mouseClicked
```

Even though the mouse click is initiating the action the JTable event sneaks in before mousePressed. Why is it not...

```
1 mousePressed
2 event=javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent[ source=javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel 673443626 ~{0} firstIndex= 0 lastIndex= 0 isAdjusting= true ]
3 event=javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent[ source=javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel 673443626 ={0} firstIndex= 0 lastIndex= 0 isAdjusting= false ]
4 mouseReleased
5 mouseClicked
```

The behaviour I was after is

1. click on a row
2. in mousePressed, check is row selected?
3. no - just select row.
4. yes - perform some action.

What happens at the moment is that both steps 3 & 4 happen at once when clicking on an unselected row. There is no mouse event which can be used to detect if the row is selected or not - it will always be selected.

Or to put it another way...when you mouse-click on a row in JTable how can you test during the click event whether the row was not selected just prior to the click event?

Here is an SSCCE...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JTableRowSelectTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Object rowData[][] = {{"Row1-Column1"}, {"Row2-Column1"}};
        Object columnNames[] = {"Column One"};
        final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                final int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (row >= 0 && table.isRowSelected(row)) {
                    System.out.println("mouseClicked on selected row");
                } else {
                    // never reached.
                    System.out.println("mouseClicked on un-selected row");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                final int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (row >= 0 && table.isRowSelected(row)) {
                    System.out.println("mousePressed on selected row");
                } else {
                    // never reached.
                    System.out.println("mousePressed on un-selected row");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouseReleased");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: better should be from code ...

Comment: Why do you use `MouseListener`, what is the purpose?

Comment: How else can you distinguish between a row being selected via a mouse click instead of say moving the selection using the arrow keys.

Comment: @mKorbel - SSCCE added.

Comment: +1 for SSCCE/MCVE, but missing (there) any goal

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding over how event as delivered.  The `ListSelectionModel` is been notified BEFORE your `MouseListener` because the `JTable` has it's own `MouseListener` which is notified before you...

Comment: @spr *"How else can you distinguish between a row being selected via a mouse click instead of say moving the selection using the arrow keys"* - Why is that important...?

Comment: Imagine each row contains an acme widget. When the user clicks on a widget, loads of useful info about that widget is displayed. If the user likes what they see they can add X items of the widget to their virtual basket by clicking on the row X times, very convenient as the mouse is already over the row and the screen is big so you do not want to keep moving the mouse back and forth between the row and an "add" button. However, you do not want it adding a widget the first time it is selected when clicked. Now, please run SSCCE and explain how to reach "mouseClicked on un-selected" statement.

Comment: Also, please see SSCCE in my answer below. Obviously if there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem: determine which event has triggered selection change. The solution is:

```
if (EventQueue.getCurrentEvent() instanceof MouseEvent) {
  // handler for mouse
} else if (EventQueue.getCurrentEvent() instanceof KeyEvent) {
  // handler for key
}
```

Simply use it in your ListSelectionListener. I'm not sure whether this approach is absolutely correct, but it worked for me.

Thanks to @mKorbel. There is another possibility to check whether the selection change was made per mouse or keyboard. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186054/java-listselectionlistener-interface-with-keyboard).

Comment: please my question, the ListSelectionListener isn't responsible to returns those events too???

Comment: @mKorbel sorry for my bad english but i cannot undertand your question. As I know ListSelectionListener has no access to the key/mouse event which has triggered the selection change.

Comment: agreed, [but I can see ...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12186054/714968), please to update, edit your answer by using AWTEventListener, and/or with link to linked thread

Comment: Sergiy - thanks, but I think you misunderstood either the original question or my answer to alex2410. He asked why I was using MouseListener and my response was why I was using it. I have added an SSCCE which should hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @SPR result from MouseListener is really good described in linked thread, this is about standard, how JTable react to mouse/key events, your mouseClicked and Pressed only to simulating an events e.getValueIsAdjusting(true/false) from ListSelectionListener, now the question, really whats goal by using MouseListener or whats/will be the goal

Comment: @SPR I'm see your point 4th. (4. yes - perform some action.) but doesn't make me some sense without details

Comment: Imagine each row contains an acme widget. :) When the user clicks on a widget, loads of useful info about that widget is displayed. If the user likes what they see they can add X items of the widget to their virtual basket by clicking on the row X times, very convenient as the mouse is already over the row and the screen is big so you do not want to keep moving the mouse back and forth between the row and an "add" button. However, you do not want it adding a widget the first time it is selected. Currently we double-click X times, but a single click would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution although it feels like a bit of a hack and a bit smelly in that you have to use information from another event - getValueIsAdjusting(). It will only work in mousePressed() as well.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JTableRowSelectTest {

    private static boolean isValueAdjusting = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Object rowData[][] = {{"Row1-Column1"}, {"Row2-Column1"}};
        Object columnNames[] = {"Column One"};
        final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouseClicked");
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                final int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (row >= 0 && table.isRowSelected(row) && !isValueAdjusting) {
                    System.out.println("mousePressed on selected row " + row);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("mousePressed on un-selected row " + row);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouseReleased");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                isValueAdjusting = e.getValueIsAdjusting();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```