# getValueAt() doubled entries into database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I write a small program which uses JTable (in this case t1) and implements a ListSelectionListener, so by clicking a row, the data from it will be put in the database (I use mysql and connect through JDBC).

```
//  t1 is a JTable
t1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
t1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

           int row = t1.getSelectedRow();

           try {
               String sql = "INSERT INTO xxx (x1, x2, x3) VALUES(?,?,?)";

               PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

               int col1 = (int)t1.getValueAt(row, 0);
               int col2 = (int)t1.getValueAt(row, 1);
               int col3 = (int)t1.getValueAt(row, 2);

               pst.setLong(1, col1);
               pst.setLong(2, col2);
               pst.setLong(3, col3);

               pst.addBatch();

               pst.executeBatch();
        } 

           catch (SQLException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works fine except that each row is put in the database twice. For example if I select third row, I get it two times in the database. It looks to me like it makes a one entry when pressing mouse and one when releasing, it does not appear when I use keyboard arrows. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below logic

```
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if ( e.getValueIsAdjusting() ){
                return;
             }
             if (e.getSource() == table.getSelectionModel() && 
                 table.getRowSelectionAllowed() ) {
               int selected = table.getSelectedRow();
               System.out.println("Column 1 : " + table.getValueAt(selected, 0));
               System.out.println("Column 2 : " + table.getValueAt(selected, 1));
               System.out.println("Column 3 : " + table.getValueAt(selected, 2));
             }
        }
    });
```

I looked at this post [java-listselectionlistener-interface-with-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186054/java-listselectionlistener-interface-with-keyboard/12193333#12193333)